# Where I get php logs using docker image php-fpm:8.0

Tags: php, docker

I build a php container and I want to mount a volume with all logs but I don't know where I can access to them ?

my files nside my container are all empty:

```
alternatives.log  apt  btmp  dpkg.log  faillog  lastlog  wtmp
root@fb8247640bd8:/var/log# cat faillog 
root@fb8247640bd8:/var/log# cat lastlog
```